# LXD Container fails to SSH out to AWS

Tags: ssh, lxc

Workstation -> Local LXC -> AWS

I have copied over the .ssh keys and config from my main workstation into an LXD container on it. I have also cleared my ip tables which was an issue with docker I believe preventing my bridge from accessing the internet. I do have access now.

Unfortunately the connection times out when I try to SSH out :(

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020                            
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config                                    
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for rabbit-dev                     
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                                
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no  
files                                                                                 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *                           
debug1: Connecting to ec2-##-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com [##.###.###.###] por 
t 22.                                                                                 
debug1: connect to address ##.###.###.### port 22: Connection timed out               
ssh: connect to host ec2-##-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection t 
imed out
```

My ~/.ssh/config contains

```
Host rabbit-dev
HostName ec2-##-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dev_company.pem
LocalForward 11003 rabbitmq.internal.dev.company.com:80
LocalForward 11004 rabbitmq.internal.dev.company.com:5672
User ec2-user 
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Using a packet capture utility like `tcpdump` on your machine (not from within the LXC container, but from the host), do you see TCP packets going out to your AWS instance on port 22? If so, that rules out bridging or firewalling on your machine and you should then be looking at the AWS Security Group settings.

Comment: I used a similar tool and there was no traffic. In fact if I ping google I get no packets back and forth. However for apt-get it does download packages.

Comment: That suggests a networking/firewalling issue between the container and the host. Are there firewall rules set (filter, nat, ...)?

Comment: I don't run ufw on my host or the container... I'm at the point where I think :22 needs to be port forwarded or a proxy setup but unfortunately I have very limited networking experience... iptables etc ... so its a bit steep of a learning curve right now :(